# Does mv not remove transferred files from source while other files are still in transfer?

Tags: mv, coreutils

I am moving 100G files from an external hard drive to another external hard drive,

```
mv /external/hdd1/sourcedir /external/hdd2/destdir
```

While it is in process,  I found that the files copied to the destination still exist in the source. Am I hallucinating? If not, why and when does that happen? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `mv -vn /external/hdd1/sourcedir /external/hdd2/destdir` to get an idea of what `mv` is doing? You might not have the right permissions for the source directory and unable to delete them.

Comment: I have permissions to remove any files.

Comment: Did the verbose output shed any light? AFAIK the only issues are permissions or if the transfer did not complete cleanly.

Comment: (1) I cancelled the transfer. Just before I cancelled it, It was in process and some files have been completely transferred, and some files were under transfer, and the rest were waiting to be transferred. The transferred files still exist in the source as well as in the destination. I didn't start the move  with `-vn`. (2) I ran some test with `mv -vn` for just two small files, the first file is copied and removed before the other is copied and then removed. Can the number of files and the size to be transferred  be the reason of the difference between the two transfers?

Answer (score 0):

Each file or folder explisitly spesifide is removed after it is copied
https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/mv.c

It's safer to use rsync then rm

Comment: Thanks. But I have experienced differently

Comment: @Tim the files you observed were in a sub folder, not explicitly passed to mv.

Comment: What @user1133275 is referring to is better explained at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mv.html